# Display sequence of months in *ngFor by including missing months

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, ngfor

I'm trying to inject this object `{"view":"monthName","count":0}` in place of missing months of JSON `this.osData` in a sequence of calendar months.

The problem I'm facing is that months are repeated and the sequence is also not proper.

Plunker link [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Q6glzWL3J71sqJrW4OZJ?p=preview)

The logic that I tried is given below:

```
 tempData.forEach((cardData)=> {
     cardData.cardData.forEach((view)=>{
       months.forEach((month)=>{
         if(month==view.view){
            console.log(tempData);
         }  else{
           cardData.cardData.push({"view":month,count:0})      
           }
      })  
     })
   })
 }
```

Please let me know what's going wrong with the above scenario.
Or is there any functionality that can be validated from HTML side to inject missing months with value 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.push` will always add new item to the end of the array. Here you should use `Array.splice` instead. The syntax for inserting item into specific index of array is as below:

```
myArr.splice(2, 0, 'newItem');   // insert newItem into myArr at index 2
```

Refer the fixed **[Plunder demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/LH0VZOudqiZk1eukbAgH?p=preview)**.